# load webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html"); to emulator not load mobile

Tags: javascript, android

I am calling a `javascript code` and read a lot of activity and open to the addresses that it will clamp simulator but not on mobile.

**code:**

```
web_pay.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web_pay.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        JSInterface = new JavaScriptInterface();
        web_pay.addJavascriptInterface(JSInterface, "cc");
        web_pay.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {       web_pay.loadUrl("javascript:window.cc.show(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);");

            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                handler.proceed();
            }

        });
        web_pay.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
    }
    public class JavaScriptInterface {
     //   Context mContext;

        //  Instantiate the interface and set the context
      //  JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
         //   mContext = c;
      //  }

        public String changeActivity() {
            Toast.makeText(pay.this, "lode

}
```

code: JavaScript

```
<html>
<head>
<body onload="test1();">
</body>
<script>
function test(a){
var form = document.createElement("form");
          form.setAttribute("method", "POST");
            form.setAttribute("action", "https://bpm.shaparak.ir/pgwchannel/startpay.mellat");
            form.setAttribute("target", "_self");
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "RefId");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value",a);
            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
            document.body.appendChild(form);
            form.submit();
            document.body.removeChild(form);
}

function test1(){
var a=cc.changeActivity();`enter code here`
test(a);
}
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

changecode:
  web_pay.postUrl("https://bpm.shaparak.ir/pgwchannel/startpay.mellat", EncodingUtils.getBytes(send, "UTF-8"));